# How can I insert data from SQL Server to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I would like to write a query with data based on a SQL Server table and insert the results into a SQL Azure table.  Is this possible in SQL Server Management Studio?

For example:

```
SELECT stuff
INTO AzureTable
FROM SqlServerTable
```

Comment: If you don't have to do it repeatedly lots of times, you can use the Import/Export tool that comes with the Mangement Studio.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I ended up using GenerateScripts with a Sql Azure target. It did take updating to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (the SP1 was critical) however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's possible to do something similar to that with a linked server to your SQL Azure host, but using `SELECT INTO` explicitly will not work - you'd need the destination table to exist first (see this MSDN blog post where they describe why [`SELECT INTO` is not supported in SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/04/10007212.aspx)).

If the destination tables don't already exist, you can script the objects in Management Studio ([as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee730904.aspx)) or use tools like [SQL Compare from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to do the grunt work for you.

Once the destination tables exist, you can just write insert statements (again assuming a linked server) or you could use a slightly different approach. For example, have you looked at the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard on Codeplex](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) or [SQL Data Compare from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that was helpful. As an addendum, I found that having SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 was needed.  I ended up using your directions and Generate Scripts as well as sqlcmd (needed because my .sql was too big!)